# Rotate camera image in ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my imageview. When I add a photo into it, the orientation (degree) of which is not 0°, it automatically changes the orientation to 0°. Which means it turns for example a 90° photo (vertical) into a 0° photo (horizontal). Examples can be seen on my screenshots. How can I fix that?

This is original photo:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BomQS.jpg)

This is rotated photo:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBNa0.png)

I could've used this piece of code:

```
iv_add.setRotation(degree);
```

But its not really what I need, because it rotates the imageview and not the photo.

Here is my code:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
            proj,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}


public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath) {
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }

        Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
        Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_COD) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            int rotateImage = getCameraPhotoOrientation(this, imageUri, getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preRotate(rotateImage);
            Bitmap rotBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            iv_add.setImageBitmap(rotBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Some photos are actually perfect, but some of them disappear and dont even show up in my imageview

Answer (score 0):

Using ExifInterface to get the orientation and use Matrix prerotate() to rotate image accordingly.
[ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface)
[Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix)